# Setting parts of a excel string to bold in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a string and I set the value of the string, then I want to bold 2 different word:

`oSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = "this is a test to test bold fonts";`

```
oSheet.Cells[36, 7].Characters(0, 4).Font.FontStyle = "bold";

oSheet.Cells[36, 7].Characters(10, 4).Font.FontStyle = "bold";
```

If I only use the first or the second command to set the bold font everything works fine but if I use both the whole text gets bolded?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem by running your example code *twice*.

To fix this, you need to set the remainder of your text to non-bold:

```
oSheet.Cells[36, 7].Font.FontStyle = "Regular";
oSheet.Cells[36, 7].Characters(0, 4).Font.FontStyle = "Bold";
oSheet.Cells[36, 7].Characters(10, 4).Font.FontStyle = "Bold";
```

Apparently, setting *some part* of the text to bold also changes the cell's default font property for newly inserted text.